# Is it possible to embed NLog's config file in the single exe file created when compiling a C# .NET 6.0 program?

Tags: c#, nlog, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I have a C# .NET 6.0 Winform Desktop Application that uses NLog to log to both a text file and to a RichTextBox, and it's working perfectly.

I am also able to create a single file executable of said desktop application with one exception. The NLog.config file is not embedded in the executable file, it ends up being placed in the Publish Target Location, along with the executable file. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening as I do not what the end users to be able to end the config file for NLog because they will, Murphy's Law, corrupt it, delete it, or change it and logging will end up broken.  I've searched Stackoverflow and googled my fingers off and can not find anything definitive on how to specifically set it so that the config file is embedded.

Using C# in Visual Studio 2022, Latest Build
NLog 5.0.4

Comment: Why not just configure nlog in code?  Also, even if you could embed it, if a user put their own nlog.config file in the folder, it would take precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Erik  I've tried that, but I'm missing something in translation because that breaks it as well. The documentation is a wee bit unclear to a noob, and I just end up making a bloody mess of it. If you have any suggestions that can help in converting a config file into code in C#, I'm all for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the Build Action of your `NLog.config` file ìs set to `Embedded Resource`.
You'll notice below entry in your `.csproj` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="NLog.config" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You'll have to configure the `LogManager` manually.

Read the content of that embedded file; make sure that the namespace and casing of the resource/file name matches exactly.
Load that xml into an `XmlLoggingConfiguration` and assign it to the `Configuration` property of the `LogManager`.

---

Below code makes use of the `NLog.config` file from [GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application#2-create-a-nlogconfig-file).

```
static void Main()
{
    var stream = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.NLog.config");
    string xml;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    LogManager.Configuration = XmlLoggingConfiguration.CreateFromXmlString(xml);

    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Info("Hello world!");
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading#loading-nlog-configuration-from-xamarin-resource

Comment: Thank you for your Answer pfx. I've placed that in my Program.cs file, however, in my frmMain.cs, it's telling me that logger.Info (and others) have the following error:

CS0103: The name 'logger' does not exist in the current context

What am I missing?

Comment: @StevenSheeley That `logger` instance in above code is only known within that `Main` method. I don't know about the details of your code, but if you need a logger elsewhere, you might need to call one of the `GetCurrentClassLogger` or `GetLogger` methods of `LogManager`.
The sample code above is merely to show that a logger has been set up using the embedded config.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @pfx, I was a bit lost, but now I understand, and that worked.